# Can I insert data on the edge of the graph?

Tags: c

### Can I put datas on an edge of adjacent list graph?

My requirement has these lines:

(A) Needed information:
A-1. 100 cities w/ each cities' tour time
A-2. 300 transportation among sites w/ price

(B) A graph for cities that shows direct access (100 sites w/ 300 direct routes among them)

(C) The graph consists of edges with distances

---

From (B), I thought that cities are vertices and routes(transportation) are edges.

(A. Needed information) says that transportation should have price of itself
and (C) says the edge have distances.

This is why I was curious about the way to put datas on edge.
I thought that edge is just an abstract concept, which is actually implemented by giving the address of another node to the node.

like:

```
struct AdjListNode* newNode = newAdjListNode(dest); 
newNode->next = graph->array[src].head; 
graph->array[src].head = newNode;
```

How can I implement the edges with data? Thank you.

Comment: *[...] other ways [...]* – what's the *current* way?

Comment: Could it be you are confused about the various meanings of the word "edge" in English? In graph theory, it's the connection between any two nodes (not just the ones at the 'edge' of the graph): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#edge

Comment: @Swordfish I mean that giving address of adjacent node to the node.

Comment: Where is your [mcve]?

Comment: A graph consists of *vertices* (or nodes) connected by edges, i.e. each edge is defined by a **pair** of vertices. Your code inserts a link to `dest` into the adjacency list for node `src`, i.e. defines an edge from `src` to `dest`. The only other ways I can think of representing the graphs would be to just have a large list of edges (i.e. not grouped by vertex as is the case with adjacency lists), or to have an adjacency matrix. But if you're asking whether you can associate data with an edge, yes, you can. Your `struct AdjListNode` can easily hold data (e.g. distance between cities).

Comment: @RuudHelderman Okay, it makes sense. But can I explain why I thought "edge" is edge literally? I fixed my post.

Comment: @Swordfish I'm so sorry, I wanted to ask about the concept but maybe my post was too confusing. I fixed it, thank you.

Comment: @Groo Genius how did you know that it was about distance of cities?! Thank you.

Comment: You can either give nodes or edges "weight", depending on the purpose of the graph. Suppose you are mapping a list of cities. Then you want to find the shortest path between two cities. It then makes perfect sense to let the edges represent roads, and to give them a "weight" equivalent to the distance.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can associate data with graph edges, and it's not related to the way you are representing the graph. Think of how you would solve the [shortest path problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/); you obviously need to know the distance between two nodes in your graph, and this information is a property of the edge connecting them, not the individual nodes.

In your example, you could have:

```
// create reciprocal links between nodes 'src' and 'dst',
// containing the 'distance' information
void graph_link_two_cities(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dst, int distance)
{
    {
        struct Edge* head = graph->array[src].head; 
        struct Edge* node = { .id = dst, .distance = length, .next = head });
        graph->edges[src].head = node;
    }

    {
        struct Edge* head = graph->array[dst].head; 
        struct Edge* node = { .id = src, .distance = length, .next = head });
        graph->edges[dst].head = node;
    }
}
```

Using an adjacency matrix, you would simply store the distance between `src` and `dst` into `matrix[src][dst]`.

Comment: Is it reasonable to understand this as form of Vertix -(connection) - Edge - (connection) - Vertix?

Comment: Perhaps, yes, just make sure that the `next` pointer doesn't confuse you: `array[src]` contains a list of vertices which are all connected to the `src` vertex, but not mutually. For example, if node `1` is connected to `4`, `7` and `8`, you will have a linked list resembling `array[1] -> 4 -> 7 -> 8 -> null`. This doesn't mean that `4`, `7` or `8` are mutually connected, i.e. the links you see in this list only exist to allow you to dynamically build the list of nodes connected to the source vertex.

Comment: Okay, I will not confuse it! Thank you very much Groo you saved me